# Forcing the inner part of a form to stay in the same position while changing border style

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, border, clr

I have a winform that starts out with a sizable border around it. On the form is a button which, when pressed, changes the form to border style none.

The problem is that then the inner part of the form moves up and to the left slightly. I want to make it that, no matter what border is used, the "inner" part of the form will always stay in the same spot (note: but I do still want the form to be moved around when it has a movable border selected)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Borderless form moves up and slightly left because thats the location that the form currently has,you need to count for the border.To achieve the result you are after you need to reassign the location property and to do that you need to account for the client size and the whole size(with border),the code i think is simple and it will be self-explanatory i believe:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var X = (this.Size.Width - this.ClientRectangle.Width) / 2;
    var Y = (this.Size.Height - this.ClientRectangle.Height) - X;
    Point p = new Point(Location.X + X, Location.Y + Y);
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Location = p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the padding on the parent that contains the panel with the border.  E.g.

```
public class Form10 : Form {
    Button btn = new Button { Text = "Button", Location = new Point(100, 100) };
    Panel border = new Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D };

    public Form10() {
        Controls.Add(border);
        border.Controls.Add(btn);

        btn.Click += delegate {
            if (border.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.Fixed3D) {
                border.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                border.Parent.Padding = new Padding(2);
            }
            else {
                border.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                border.Parent.Padding = new Padding(0);
            }

        };
    }
}
```